# Use powershell to download unknown files from a remote https url

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to download files from a remote url to a local folder. The filenames that exist on the remote side will never be known. Similar to how you would just use: copy c:\downloadfiles*.* c:\dump
For now let's assume the url is open to everyone (no credentials needed):

```
$localPath = "C:\dump"
$url = "https://remoteserver/folder"
$WebClient = New-Object "System.Net.WebClient"
$WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $localPath)
```

But I just keep getting:

Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."

I realize that you probably can't download with HTTP/HTTPS using wildcard but perhaps we can parse a remote file from "https://remoteserver/folder/FileList.txt" and use wildcard in there somehow, even if it's just by filetype *.jpg.

Comment: Does the url have directory listing enabled? Ie., if you go to the page in a browser, is all the file and folder names listed?

Comment: No it does not have directory listing enabled.

Comment: Well then the answer is no :) When you do `copy C:\something*`, the underlying file system globber can resolve the wildcard _because it knows all the possible file names_ - if you have no way of discovering the file names, how would PowerShell possibly know what/where to fetch?

Comment: That is what I was saying then. That it may not be possible over https like that. But what if directory listing was available? How would I do it then? I think I can convince someone to let me do that.

Comment: if directory listing is enabled for the folder, then [this will work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523870/how-to-download-all-files-from-url)

Comment: I've tried all the methods there but I can't get it to download any files. It shows me the list of files it's going to download but keep getting:Invoke-WebRequest : Access to the path 'C:\PS' is denied.
At F:\temp\script.ps1:24 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($url + $file) -Method GET -OutFile ($destPath ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], UnauthorizedAccessException

I've no problem accessing C:\PS

Comment: 1) **Nothing will work** until the server owner allows directory listings for `/folder`. 2) Please read the error carefully, you're attempting to write to a file in a directory you don't have access to

Comment: Everyone already has directory listing access and when I browse to the url in a browser I can see all the files. Sorry if I didn't make that clear. And C:\PS is a local folder on my pc which I have full access to as I just created it and am logged in as Administrator.

Comment: Is PowerShell running elevated (ie "Run as Administrator")?

Comment: Yes. But perhaps there's something wrong with the code I used from that link. Could you post the simple code for downloading all files from a url which has directory listing already enabled? Perhaps I'm having a problem downloading extension specific files like *.txt and the local C:\PS access denied error is misleading.

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe we're misunderstanding each other. I'm trying to download whatever is at https://example.com/files/ I'm not trying to download a file list which contains url's of files I want to download. I just wanted to clarify this.